# Declare a variable, having a key being a concatenation of two types

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I would like to lock the creation of an object by declaring that the keys in it are the concatenation of two types. Since it's blurry, let me picture it with some code :

```
type Letter = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

boxes: { [ID in Letter]: string }[] = ...;
```

Right now, this code allows one to create a set of boxes like this :

```
boxes = [{ A: 1 }]; // Correct
boxes = [{ D: 1 }]; // Incorrect
```

What I would like to achieve is do the same thing, but incorporate digits in the keys. Something like this :

```
type Letter = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2';

boxes: { [ID in (Letter + '-' + Digit)]: string }[] = ...;
```

Where a user could then create this

```
boxes = { 'A-1': 1 };
```

**Is it possible, and if so, how ?**

*PS : the keys have to be dynamic, i.e. I can't declare a new type made of all possible combinations*

Comment: Related https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579

Comment: Thank you for the link !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, there is no support for manipulation of string literals.

If your set of strings is limited (as in the provided example) then your best bet is to generate all the combinations (should not be that many and you could write a script to generate them)

If you have a lot of possible combinations, then you might do better with just a simple index signature.

Another approach is to redefine your data structure in a way where the second part of the index is actually a nested object, it's more verbose, but typesafe:

```
type Letter = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2';

type UnionOfJustOneProperty<T extends string, TAll extends string> = T extends string ? { [P in T]: string } & { [P in Exclude<TAll, T>]?: never }: never;
let boxes: { [P in Letter]: UnionOfJustOneProperty<Digit,Digit> }[] = [
    { 
        A: { "0": "value"},
        B: { "1": "value"},
        C: { "0": "value", /* "1": "" */} // the commented code causes an error, we can only have one key in the object
    }
];
```

Comment: I could hard-code the values, but this is a [mvce], the actual types have 10 to 20 keys each and there is 3 of them ... This would create a huge type. And as for the second option, I thought that too, but the requirement of the API is to have an hyphen-built key (for better handling purposes).

Comment: @trichetriche I definitely recall seeing a type in angular or jquery that contains **ALL** the HTTP error codes ..If you just need to create it once and it is useful for a long time might be worth spelling out all the options

Comment: @trichetriche I would avoid it if possible, but if you know the keys, and the language can't do better I would go for this approach (writing out all the options). It's less bad than not having types for it at all, and less bad is the best we can do sometimes :)

Comment: I agree on that last sentence, but unfortunately the current base types aren't exhaustive, they're used to handle permissions on angular components, meaning that every new component creates new permissions ... And since the functions that check the permissions use the base types for their parameters, this is more of an intellisense convenience on 3-4 parts of the app. This was an open question to know if it was possible, rather than an actual need !

Answer (score 2):

`A-1` string requires to evaluate `(Letter + '-' + Digit)` at runtime. It's impossible to achieve type safety for such keys in TypeScript.

If type safety is a requirement, keys like `A-1` can't be considered an appropriate way.

Comment: So there's no way to do it, except waiting for the [regex typing proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) (thank you @Aleksey) to be accepted ?

Comment: @trichetriche That proposal has been on the books since 2016, don't think it's going to make it in any time soon, it is not on the roadmap

Comment: @trichetriche I wouldn't expect regexp proposal any time soon, so using an alternative way to store data (e.g. Titian's proposal) is your best bet.

Comment: Even though you answered my question, I'm going to mark the other answer as the right one, since people looking for the same issue would want a workaround. But thank you for answering me !